# Hive - Load delimited data with special character cause off position

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, delimiter, pipeline

Let's say I want to create a simple table with 4 columns in Hive and load some pipe-delimited data.

```
CREATE table TEST_1 (
COL1  string,
COL2  string,
COL3  string,
COL4  string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
;
```

Raw Data:

```
123|456|Dasani Bottled \| Water|789
```

What I expect for Col3 value is "**Dasani Bottled \| Water**", it has some special character "**\|**" in the middle thus cause Hive table column off position starting at COL3 because I create the table using "**|**" as the delimiter.  **The special character \|  does have a pipe | character within it.**

Is there any way to resolve the issue so Hive can load data correctly?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

you can add the `ESCAPED BY` clause to your table creation like this to allow character escaping

```
CREATE table TEST_1 (
COL1  string,
COL2  string,
COL3  string,
COL4  string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ESCAPED BY '\'
;
```

From the Hive documentation

> Enable escaping for the delimiter characters by using the 'ESCAPED BY'
>   clause (such as ESCAPED BY '\')  Escaping is needed if you want to
>   work with data that can contain these delimiter characters.
>
> A custom NULL format can also be specified using the 'NULL DEFINED AS'
>   clause (default is '\N').